# Fuzzy String Comparison - Detecting shorthand names

Tags: c#, shorthand, similarity, fuzzy-comparison

This will be the second time I'll be asking about computational linguistics/fuzzy string matching but this time, it's not about stemming.

My first problem was to deduplicate a database using fuzzy string matching, and I already accomplished that. Now, I have to detect if a string is a shorthand of another string. For example:

- JOHN ADRIAN FREEMAN WELTER is equal to JAF Welter or JAFWelter
- MICROSOFT OFFICE is equal to MS OFFICE
- BUILDING is equal to BLDG

I am currently using the .Net version of SimMetrics for my first problem. So, is there a method in SimMetrics that can solve my problem? If none, then what is the best way to solve this?

Here's the metrics implemented in SimMetrics:

- Hamming distance
- Levenshtein distance
- Needleman-Wunch distance or Sellers Algorithm
- Smith-Waterman distance
- Gotoh Distance or Smith-Waterman-Gotoh distance
- Block distance or L1 distance or City block distance
- Monge Elkan distance
- Jaro distance metric
- Jaro Winkler
- SoundEx distance metric
- Matching Coefficient
- Dice’s Coefficient
- Jaccard Similarity or Jaccard Coefficient or Tanimoto coefficient
- Overlap Coefficient
- Euclidean distance or L2 distance
- Cosine similarity
- Variational distance
- Hellinger distance or Bhattacharyya distance
- Information Radius (Jensen-Shannon divergence)
- Harmonic Mean
- Skew divergence
- Confusion Probability
- Tau
- Fellegi and Sunters (SFS) metric
- TFIDF or TF/IDF
- FastA
- BlastP
- Maximal matches
- q-gram
- Ukkonen Algorithms

I'm not that familiar with all of these algorithms. The ones I've already used here are Leveshtein Distance, Needleman-Wunch, Jaro-Winkler, SoundEx, and TF/IDF. And I think these algorithms are not enough to solve this shorthand name problem

Comment: can you provide a bit more info on how did you do this: `My first problem was to deduplicate a database using fuzzy string matching, and I already accomplished that`

Answer (score 2):

You would most probably need custom methods.  Here is what I'd try:

1. JOHN ADRIAN FREEMAN WELTER is equal to JAF Welter or JAFWelter

Here, you can use the first letters of the words to get the abbreviation.  If all occurrences are such that the last word is full, this most likely gives you unique resolutions, otherwise chances are you will find other word sequences that have the same abbreviation (e.g. JAFW: Java as foreign word)

2. MICROSOFT OFFICE is equal to MS OFFICE

Here, you need a dictionary of known words and recognize that *Microsoft* can be put together from *Micro* and *Soft* (assuming both are in your dictionary) and use the first approach on these

3. BUILDING is equal to BLDG

Here, you will need a dictionary of words and custom abbreviations (I don't think you will find one rule/algorithm that can compute the abbreviation of all words)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I was making an algorithm similar to your answer in no. 1. But, I ditched since it always give me false negatives if I set the threshold lower and false positives if too high. I'll just improve it then.